# How can I prevent the user from selecting the div that contains all the text and tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-11, contenteditable

I am writing a WYSIWUG typing tool for IE11. The contentEditable div can contain span and br tags which can be edited by the user.

**Desirable functionality**: prevent the user from inadvertently select the main contentEditable div that contains all text and tags.

**Issue I'm facing**: if the user selects text sometimes the selection includes the contentEditable div (usually with a mouse selection or for example with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>), resulting in undesired behaviour.

Here's an example:

```
<div id="textBox" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
    <span style="color: black;">Hello</span>
    <span style="color: blue;">text text</span>
    <br>
</div>
```

In the above example the user must be able to delete/change the contents of the div but when selecting text he must not be able to select the div itself. Currently when for example the user press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> the range.startContainer and range.endContainer will be the div itself: I would like to select just what it's contained in the div, so it the startContainer and endContainer would be the first span and last span tag.

I tried to use this css but it will also prevent the selection of child elements.

```
user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
```

I was wondering if there is some css or simple solution I can try to prevent the selection of the div or if I have to use `getSelection()` and range to programmatically control the selection.

Thanks.

Comment: unclear what you are trying to have them select. Can you show some basic HTML to make it clear.

Comment: added an example

Comment: Okay so the issue is they are selecting the div id="textBox" in their selection?

Comment: Yes, that’s the problem!